# Restore a disabled Azure subscription

Tags: azure

We got a test subscription in Azure from our school.

Unfortunately I managed to disable my student subscription in Azure. Does anyone know how I can get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From article from below link, i think you will have to contact azure support

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-subscription-become-disable/

> The Azure subscription is cancelled
>
> To reactivate a subscription, you must create a support ticket. To
>   create a support ticket to re-enable an Azure subscription see the
>   article How to Create a Support Ticket for Azure Billing and
>   Subscription Issues.